# I am having a problem with changing my date format

Tags: java, android

Hello guys I am having a problem in changing the date from one form to another. I have searched through stack overflow and made one solution but it is giving wrong result.
As I have date in this format: 
2019-04-16 05:50:44
and I wanna convert it to this format 
Apr 4
I made this code for conversion

```
SimpleDateFormat spf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
  Date newDate=spf.parse("2019-04-16 05:50:44");
  spf= new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
String date = spf.format(newDate);
```

And the result I am getting is Jan 16 and I don't know why ... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `mm` means minutes. You want `MM` in the date part; likewise you almost certainly want `HH` instead of `hh`.

Comment: You can look at here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: oh Ok ,, so the format would be yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss    .... Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SimpleDateFormat documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

> M Month in year
>
> m Minute in hour

So, your code should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat spf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date newDate=spf.parse("2019-04-16 05:50:44");
spf= new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
String date = spf.format(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime                                            // Represent a date and time-of-day but without a time zone or offset-from-UTC. 
.parse(
    "2019-04-16 05:50:44".replace( " " , "T" )           // Comply with ISO 8601 standard format by replacing the SPACE in the middle with a `T`. 
)                                                        // Returns an immutable `LocalDateTime` object. 
.format(                                                 // Generate a `String` containing text representing the value of this date-time object. 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd" , Locale.US )  // The Locale determines the human language and cultural norms used in localizing the words and formatting generated to the resulting text. 
)                                                        // Returns a `String`.
```

> Apr 16

## java.time

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Convert input to comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

```
String input = "2019-04-16 05:50:44".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` as the input lacks indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

You want just the month and day, so use the [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) class. I suspect you could make use of this class in other parts of your code.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.from( ldt ) ;
```

Generate a string in localized format.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH; // Or Locale.US etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd" , locale );
String output = md.format( f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "md.toString(): " + md );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

> md.toString(): --04-16
>
> output: avr. 16

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).